# 八光流柔術 and traditionnal light spectrum vision

Tags: culture

On the Hakkoryu Jujutsu website we can read

> The name “Hakkoryu” is based on a philosophical Japanese view of the color spectrum as being divided into nine bands of light. The eighth shade is infrared, which is invisible to the naked eye but extremely powerful, both characteristics apparent in Hakkoryu’s techniques.

But I don't find anything on that subject. I'd like to read more about this philosophical Japanese view. Any clue ? Sorry if that's the wrong place to ask.